# Does nasm support casting a floating-point expression into an integer?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This is for an easy way to write down fixed points.

Something to this effect:

```
%define FIXEDP_LITERAL(num) (int) (num * 65536)
```

That's invalid code, obviously (probably). This macro will be used in instructions as operands and in define directives. Is it possible to cast from a float to an integer in nasm expressions, such that nasm will use the expression as an integer (i.e. so `dd FIXEDP_LITERAL(3.5)` should place an integer constant, not a floating-point constant).

Comment: So you want to write an integer constant expression involving decimal fractions?  Like some way to make `dd 2 * 0.5` equivalent to `dd 1`?  I don't know off the top of my head, but haven't checked the NASM manual.

Comment: @PeterCordes Correct, this is just to make fixed-point easier for the coder, it's not at all a necessity. I couldn't find this in the manual, would be a shame if this isn't supported.

Comment: You can probably get most of what you want via right-shift or division for fixed-point.  Given that floating-point numbers can't exactly represent most decimal fractions (only ones with a power-of-2 denominator) I wouldn't be surprised if there's no support for assemble-time float->int conversion.  You don't really want rounding errors to maybe give you `0` instead of `1` if you write `int ( 3 * (1.0/3.0) )` instead of limiting yourself to 0.5, 0.25, 0.125 and so on.